# The orders of bean validation default parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, bean-validation

I am currently trying to provide a custom validation message using bean validation.

Currently using spring mvc 3.1.1 + apache bean validation.

In my bean, i specify :

```
@Size(min=1, max=50)
private String title;
```

And in my messages.properties :

```
Size.addForm.title=The title must not be empty and must not exceed {1} characters.
```

From experiment, i found out that :

- {0} refers to 'title'
- {1} refers to the max, which is 50
- {2} refers to the min, which is 1

and it'll be displayed as `The title must not be empty and must not exceed 50 characters.` which is correct.

But all these are from experiments. I wonder **whether there are documentations stating the order of parameters for the default constraints** ?

I tried hopefully using `Size.addForm.title=The title must not be empty and must not exceed {max} characters.` basing on the default ValidationMessages.properties but ends up with NumberFormatException on the `{max}`. I think it has something to do with the interpolations ?

---

### Update

So, each of these fails independently with NumberFormatException on the `{max}` :

- *messages.properties* : Size.addForm.title=The title must not be empty and must not exceed **{max}** characters.
- *messages.properties* : Size=The title must not be empty and must not exceed **{max}** characters.
- *messages.properties* : javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=The title must not be empty and must not exceed **{max}** characters.
- *ValidationMessages.properties* : Size.addForm.title=The title must not be empty and must not exceed **{max}** characters.
- *ValidationMessages.properties* : Size=The title must not be empty and must not exceed **{max}** characters.

This is the stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "max"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceSupport.createMessageFormat(MessageSourceSupport.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource.getMessageFormat(ResourceBundleMessageSource.java:281)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource.resolveCode(ResourceBundleMessageSource.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessageInternal(AbstractMessageSource.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:146)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getMessage(RequestContext.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.initErrorMessages(BindStatus.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.getErrorMessages(BindStatus.java:273)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag.exposeAttributes(ErrorsTag.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.writeTagContent(AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
```

This is the only one that works with the named parameter, it **has to be ValidationMessages.properties, and it has to be exactly the key that exists in the default resource bundle by the jsr 303 implementation** :

- **ValidationMessages.properties** : javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=you know wad, the size must be between **{min}** and **{max}**

Basically the current conclusion is, by default, i cannot use named parameters on my specific messages. The named parameter **only works** when i *override the exact key* on the default jsr303 resourcebundle **&&** when i use the same default jsr303 resourcebundle file name, which is *ValidationMessages.properties*

I prefer avoiding having to play with interpolation for now, hence the original question on how to find out that {0} or {1} or {2} refers to what in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

[JSR 303 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/), 4.3.1.1. "Default message interpolation algorithm"

> - 4 -   Message parameters are extracted from the message string. Those matching the name of an attribute of the
>     constraint are replaced by the value of that attribute in the constraint declaration.

I read this like: you should use the name of the annotation properties for the message parameter, instead of numbers.

Appendix B "Standard ResourceBundle messages" of the specification shows some examples:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Min.message=must be greater than or equal to {value}
javax.validation.constraints.Max.message=must be less than or equal to {value}
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=size must be between {min} and {max}
javax.validation.constraints.Digits.message=numeric value out of bounds (<{integer} digits>.<{fraction} digits> expected)
```

So it seems that named paramerter are the way you should use. (That `{0}`, `{1}` and `{2}` works too, seems to be a implementation "feature")  - *But in the end, this is only the behavior of the default message interpolator, the standard defines a way how to replace them by your own.*

---

Update

The Hibernate Validation implementation seams to have an additional feature to format values `${validatedValue:<format>}`. -- Maybe that helps you with your `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

@See [Hibernate Validator Reference, Chapter 5.3. MessageInterpolator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-bootstrapping.html#section-message-interpolator)

Comment: Thank you ! I 100% agree that the named parameters are the way to go, but it's quite bad news that {0} and friends is just an implementation feature, because the named parameters dont work well with me. I have updated my original post with the latest experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Better use:

```
    @Size(max=99)
    @NotBlank
    private String title;
```

since `@Size` allows whitespace characters, like space( ).

Answer (score 0):

- for `Size.foo.bar` interpolation with names doesn't work
- however for `size.foo.bar` and `baz.foo.bar` it does (when validation annotation name isn't used; check is case sensitive)

Checked with `message.properties` file which is added in `WebAppConfig` extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` like:

```
  @Bean
  public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
  }

  @Override
  public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
  }
```