# org.springframework.validation.Errors.rejectValue doesn't escape values

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to add escaped values to an error message in a Spring MVC Validator

```
final Object[] vatErrorArray = new String[2];
   vatErrorArray[0] = "aaa";
   vatErrorArray[1] = "bbb";
errors.rejectValue("vatfield", "vendor.vat.number.invalid.pattern.generic", vatErrorArray, "Invalid VAT");
```

where `vendor.vat.number.invalid.pattern.generic` is as follows:

```
vendor.vat.number.invalid.pattern.generic=VAT Number's pattern is invalid for {0}. Valid pattern: {1}.
```

Unfortunately, the displayed error message doesn't contain the escaped values:

```
VAT Numbers pattern is invalid for {0}. Valid pattern: {1}.
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS I am using Spring MVC version 4.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: This is not a very good answer, but *might* help - what happens if you change `vatErrorArray` to a `String[]` instead of `Object[]`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the single quote in `Number's` to two single quotes (`''`).

I haven't tried it myself but am basing this mostly on the content of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22380243/325900) question, and the MessageFormat docs it links to, plus the fact that your single quote seems to be disappearing.

Comment: Replacing the single quote in the message (_Number's_) by two double quotes (_Number''s_) solved the problem. Many thanks.